# Make google map blurry

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, blur

I am trying to make the google map (javascript api v3) blurry while the focus is on some other element.

What i am doing right now is simply adding:

```
blur(5px);
```

to the map-container, which does work! 
unfortunately, the map gets distorted sometimes. 
This lead me to the conclusion that there gotta be a better solution, rather than simply adding some CSS rules. Maybe by using the options or styles of the API itself?

Comment: As far as I know, the current API is not capable of blurring other elements while zooming.

Comment: thanks!
but i am no trying to blur out while zooming, i am trying to blur the map out while the focus is on some other DOM element